# Load spring xml config dynamically

Tags: java, xml, spring, classloader, kotlin

At the startup time of a spring app, I want to scan a path on the computer, find the jar files and build a spring application context from an xml config files inside them. Every thing is OK to add jar file to the classpath and making an ApplicationContext. But I can't find any beans from new context. All of needed dependencies are available in the jar files in the specific path on computer (via a maven copier plugin) expect those dependencies which are in the base spring project (for example spring dependency itself).
The code is (In Kotlin language):

```
var loader = URLClassLoader(arrayOf(entry.toFile().toURL()), Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
...
val context = ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/$name")//name is xml file. I'm sure the address in classpath is right. context is not creating when the address in wrong. for example: classpath://$name
val services = context.getBeanNamesForType(IService::class.java)//services is empty
```

I have tried many other ways to load the xml but none of them was successful. for example:

```
val beans = DefaultListableBeanFactory(applicationContext)
val reader = XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beans)
reader.beanClassLoader = loader
reader.resourceLoader = resourceLoader
reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD)
jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry).use {
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(EncodedResource(InputStreamResource(it)))
}
beans.preInstantiateSingletons()
```

the xml inside jar file looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<import resource="classpath*:/xxx-logic-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="aa.bbb.ccc.server"/>
</beans>
```

It's really interesting: When I define regular Beans instead using package scaning feature, I can get the bean in a sort of code

Comment: `context:component-scan` use MAGIC that is not compatible with `URLClassLoader`. No luck.

Comment: @talex but I have used ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with exactly same xml (with package-scanning and schedule features) in regular spring boot apps or simple spring apps. The only different is adding class loader. How the spring add import to other XMLs in regular apps? It must have a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately. With MAGIC it happens very often. The rison is that Java have no function to enumerate classes and subpackages in package and `component-scan` depends on this feature. Current implementation use trick that read `jar` files as simple `zip` and get list of classes. But it only work default class loader. In theory it is possible to implemnt this for other ClassLoader, but no one did it yet.

Comment: @talex thanks for your answer. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer from @talex guided me. I fixed it by setting the current class loader:

```
val loader = URLClassLoader(arrayOf(entry.toFile().toURL()), Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = loader
```